# How to bind remaining query parameters to a dictionary in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using model binding for an ASP.NET Core application, and it has several known attributes configured, and then a dictionary where I want any additional URL attributes to be added. I want my query string to look like this:

```
/foobar?Id=5&Status=pending&SpecialKey=test
```

And for it to populate my model where the property `Id = 5, Status = Pending`, and to have a Dictionary called `ExtraParams` with one item, the key of "SpecialKey" and the value of "test".

Here's my model now:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class MyCustomModel
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Status { get; set; }
        public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Nickname { get; set; }
        public string? DisplayName { get; set; }

        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, object> ExtraParams { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    }
}
```

As it stands now, only Id/Status get populated. The only way I can get anything in `ExtraParams` is by using the query string notation of `ExtraParams[key]=test` which I do not want.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple string parameter that its value is a jason string encoded by base 64 encoder? You can easily get the encoded value and then decode on your backend and convert to the main json. After that deserialize to your desired dictionary.

Comment: I am replacing an existing API, so I cannot change the format of the request

Comment: You mean you can only make changes in the backend? If you cann't change the request, please clarify that how the data are passd from the clients!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar usecase. Following are the steps that I used

- Add an optional parameter to Controller action method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllItemsAsync(string searchString, int? pageNo = 1, int? pageSize = 10, Dictionary<string, object> filters = null)
{
   <My-Controller-Logic>
}
```

- Created an ActionFilterAttribute override

```
    public class QueryStringActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private const string _additionalParamsFieldName = "filters";

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var kvp in context.HttpContext.Request.Query)
            {
                if (!context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                {
                    filters.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
            context.ActionArguments[_additionalParamsFieldName] = filters;
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
```

- Added the Action filter attribute to my controller action method

```
[QueryStringActionFilter]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllItemsAsync(string searchString, int? pageNo = 1, int? pageSize = 10, Dictionary<string, object> filters = null)
{
   <My-Controller-Logic>
}
```

This way all my query parameters other than searchString, pageNo and pageSize get populated inside filters.

Answer (score 0):

One way is populating all the parameters into a dictionary on your back-end using this sample code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Keys.Cast<string>()
            .ToDictionary(k => k, v => HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[v]);
```

or even [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpUtility_ParseQueryString_System_String_) could be helpful.